# what does first <T> in "<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)" stands for?

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of return type. I was reading Java API for the interface ExecutorService:

[image]

I know for `submit(Callable<T> task)`, it returns a Future object of T type, however, there is another `<T>` in front of `Future<T>`, what does it represent?

Comment: It's a generic method declaration, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leading `<T>` is defining `T` as a type parameter (aka generics), in simple words, the function uses a generic type parameter called T where T is a **type** (at the time of writing this (Java 1.8), only reference types are supported)

```
<T> void fn(T t); // T is a type parameter
```

For example, Integer could be concrete type

```
<Integer>fn(1);
```

The compiler can often infer the type as follows

```
fn(1)
```

In your example, submitting a `Callable<Integer>` returns a `Future<Integer>`

```
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(callableInteger);
Integer futureResult = future.get(); //type-saftey powered by generics
```

You can check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) out for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It's declaring a type variable that has scope only for the `submit()` method.

An `Executor` is not generic, but some of its methods use generic types, which are declared between the method modifiers and the return type.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `T` is the type (class) of the value returned from the `Future`.

So if the task you run with your `Future` returns a `String`, then `T` is `String`. Likewise, if it returns an integer, then `T` is `Integer`.

Example:

```
Future<String> future = executorService.submit( new Callable<String>(){
    public String call() throws Exception{
        return "the result";
    }
});
String result = future.get();
assert "the result".equals( result );
```

Answer (score 1):

stands for Template.  Instead of seperately coding for a List of integers , List of floats , and so on, simply code once for a generic type T, then assign to the different types as required.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of generic method. Generic methods allow "type parameters"(in this case ) to be used to express "dependencies" among the types of one or more arguments to a method and/or its return type.

In this case,  Future submit(Callable task),  in front of Future indicates the dependency among type specified for Future and Callable.

In another case,  void copy(List dest, List src),  indicates that T and S have a dependency which is S extends T.

If there isn't such a dependency, a generic method should not be used.
Ex: void fn(T t) - since there is only one arg and no return type, no need to specify leading  to indicate a generic method.

More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).